# Service Stops Logging On Activity Destroy

Tags: android, logging, service

I am trying to run a service in the background, despite the lifecycle state of the Activity that creates it. To guarantee it's running, the service (in addition to the services it performs) also has a thread that logs once a second. Finally, it also has logs in onStartCommand and onDestroy.

I'm starting the service with startService() and then I bind to it. My understanding is that this should keep the service running, regardless of what happens to its creator Activity. However, if the Activity is destroyed, the service stops logging. If the Activity is simply paused, there is no problem.

The following is also true: 
1) onDestroy is never called on the service
2) I never call stopService or stopSelf after calling startService

I'm trying to figure out why the service is dying (there are no exceptions) or at the very least why it's being paused and no longer logging.

Answer (score 0):

A bound service typically lives only while it serves  application component and does not run in the background indefinitely.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Use syncadapter instead of service . if you want to transfer data between server and client .

http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Comment: I was under the impression I could use a Service as a BoundService, and a background service, provided I called both startService and bindService. Is this not the case? Is there any way to bind to a service and also have it run indefinitely?

Comment: Please can you check wheather  yo u call unbindservice in onpause() or onstop() method or use START_STICKEY onstartcommand

Comment: I only call unbindService in onDestroy, nowhere else. I don't use START_STICKY mainly because I thought this was for if you wanted Android to restart the service. I just want it to keep running after destroy. For example, if I stop the application manually, or the system destroys it to get memory, I would still like to run.

Comment: Android kill your service when memory get low . or if user forcefully kill your app . the other solution are available  but it is not viable . it drain user battery. See my edits ans it might be solve your problem using symcadapter

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of an unbound service (using startService or stopService) was that it kept running even if the user killed the app? It looks like SyncAdapter requires us to create an account in the Android account manager, which we would rather not do. Is there any way to just keep our service running?